# Pattern as a input in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying a script that could compress and delete folders which is in 'n' sublevel folders.

For example the below script could do the job for 3 sublevel folders.

```
$path = Read-Host "Enter the path"
$directory = $path +"\*\*\*"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$folders = Get-ChildItem $directory -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Select-object -ExpandProperty FullName
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
Write-Verbose "Archiving $archive"
$archive = $folder + '.zip'
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($folder, $archive, 'Optimal', $True)
Remove-Item $folder -recurse -force -Verbose
}
```

The script is working fine...My doubt is, how to input the sublevel as a input value?

In the above script I am giving the path as a input...Likewise, I wish to input the sublevel also as a input value.

For example: Enter the level:3    (This should assume the pattern like (bs* bs* bs*)
or 4 (bs* bs* bs* bs*)

Note : I had mentioned \ as bs. Because if I mention the pattern as in script, its not visible in the preview.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell allows you to replicate strings with its `*` operator:

```
PS> $numLevels = 3; $path = 'C:\path\to'; $path + ('\*' * $numLevels)
C:\path\to\*\*\*
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @jimmy20. Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment: